# PowerAutomate Flow works from PowerApps editor but don't launch from PowerApps tablet application

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

Here is my problem, quite strange and scary for me right now :

- I have an application in PowerApps that trigger multiple flows (SQL queries for example)
- when I trigger those flows from PowerApps editor everything goes well
- when I trigger those same flow, from the same application, same account, through my tablet with PowerApps application, nothing happen : no error message, no execution detected by PowerAutomate

This used to all work very well I am very confused about it and have no idea from where to start.

Any advices ?

Thx in advance

Sylvain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was solved by Microsoft in the end :

Issue: Unable to trigger flow from Power apps mobile devices.

Product team was engaged on an issue with Microsoft Power Apps where users creating or editing flows in the Microsoft Power Apps Studio have received errors when attempting to run.

Resources have found that this was caused by a recent update to the Power Apps Studio where an App Version Info check was added.

This inadvertently caused it to become incompatible with previous versions when attempting to run in the Power Apps Player app, or in the Power Apps Studio web browser.

Product team Engineers developed a new build to fix the issue and have deploying the fix to the affected environment. The issue was successfully deployed across affected regions.

I will proceed with closing the support request at this time. If you find yourself any additional issues relating to this service request, you can always re-open the request by reaching out directly to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your app in web browser,
If it doesn t trigger either, it could be something with predefined variables that u don t fill in when running a new instance...

When in editor, usually you dont follow the normal way of inserting variables...

Or...
Is there a label or other control overlapping your buttons?

Comment: Hi !
Indeed this is a good advice to find the source of the problem, when I start the app from the browser everything goes well.

Yesterday I spent half an hour explaining / showing the problem to Microsoft team, they are working on it.

I'll keep you updated :-)

Thx

Comment: Long shot question: your sql instance isn t secured by ip?

Comment: Other device = other ip

Comment: My sql server is secured by IP yes

Comment: Did it solve your problem when adding ip from other device?

Comment: no the problem was not here, when the IP thing is problematic I get an error message to identify it and make it work :-)